# Prolog convert mathematical expression into list?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to convert a mathematica expression, for example **2x*y+5z**
into a list of single elements in prolog, but the predicate

```
atom_codes(2x*y+5z, Codes)
```

gives

```
ERROR: atom_codes/2: Type error: `atom' expected, found `2x*y+5z' (a compound)
```

So how can I read the expression as a list?

Comment: `2x*y+5z` is not an *atom* in Prolog. You can put it in single quotes, then it will be an atom: `'2x*y+5z'`.

Answer (score 0):

As the other comment noted, `2x*y+5z` is not an atom. Neither is it a valid Prolog term because `2x` is not a valid term. If you wrote it as `2*x*y+5*z`, it would be a Prolog term representing the syntax tree of the expression.

So a question is where `2x*y+5z` comes from and what you want to do with it. You suggest that it comes from Mathematica; are you trying to parse some Mathematica output? If yes, you can read it to a list of codes and convert that to an atom and/or to a list of chars, which are nicer to look at:

```
?- read_line_to_codes(user_input, Codes), atom_codes(Atom, Codes), atom_chars(Atom, Chars).
|: 2x*y+5z
Codes = [50, 120, 42, 121, 43, 53, 122],
Atom = '2x*y+5z',
Chars = ['2', x, *, y, +, '5', z].
```

If you want to recover a syntax tree from this, you will have to write a parser. For that, have a look at definite clause grammars (DCGs).